# Can you do a POST to an external webform using a Ethereum smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, external-api

Can you do POST or submit a form from an external site using a smart contract? And how can this be done? Are there any examples of live code out there?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum SE. Could you improve your question style by adding information on what you have tried so far and forming sentences with at least 1 verb? :)

Answer (score 11):

Ethereum contracts are sandboxed from the world and cannot do much more than add/subtract/multiply/send on ether/invoke other contracts, etc. (There's a complete list of opcodes, I hope you get the idea.) This is to prevent DDoS attacks. (Imagine if you just told all Ethereum miners to access some web page a million times.)

A server can monitor the data from a contract and perform actions based upon it.

One such pay service is called Oraclize. (I hope some day there will be others? But Oraclize has a way to prove that they didn't mess with the data called TLSNotary.)

Oraclize does have a way to do a POST request.

You have to be extremely careful because any data you put in your POST will be visible to everyone. (Don't put a secret API key in there!)

They have a demo of this here: https://docs.oraclize.it/#simple-query

```
// the only data-source accepting 2 string arguments is 'URL' when we want it to send an HTTP POST request
// with the 2nd argument being the query-string we want to send to the given server.
// note that when the 2nd argument is a valid JSON string it will be automatically sent as JSON
oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://shapeshift.io/sendamount).success.deposit", '{"pair": "eth_btc", "amount": "1", "withdrawal": "1AAcCo21EUc1jbocjssSQDzLna9Vem2UN5"}');
```

Comment: what would be the basic structure of a simple oracle used internally and where I wouldn't need proof the data hasn't been tampered ?

Comment: The link is broken. Could you please update the link?